# Show fields in jsp based on user roles(without using spring security)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have a tabs.jsp which has links to other pages. When an admin logs in he must be given 2 extra links to add users and roles. while authenticating im able to validate if user is admin or not. on validation im returning control to a user display page if user exists if not redirecting back to login page. how do i achieve this extra 2 links if user is admin?

My controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "auth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView printStringLogin(
                @ModelAttribute("USERS") Users userAuthentication,
                HttpSession httpSession, ModelMap model) {
            System.out.println(userAuthentication.getUsers_email());
            System.out.println(userAuthentication.getUsers_password());
            UserAuthentication userAuthentication2 = new UserAuthentication();
            boolean exists = false,admin = false;
            try {
                exists = userAuthentication2.doesUserExist(
                        userAuthentication.getUsers_email(),
                        userAuthentication.getUsers_password());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (exists == true) {
                System.out.println("user present");
                httpSession.setAttribute("id", userAuthentication.getUsers_email());
                System.out.println("Session Attribute: "
                        + httpSession.getAttribute("id"));
                return new ModelAndView("redirect:employee");
            } else {
                System.out.println("user not present");
                return new ModelAndView("loginpage");
            }
    }
```

user authentication

```
public class UserAuthentication {
    public boolean doesUserExist(String uname, String passwrd) throws Exception {
        GetSession ses = new GetSession();
        Session session = ses.retSession();
        String query = "from Users as u where u.users_email = :sUname and u.users_password = :sPass";
        List list = session.createQuery(query).setString("sUname", uname)
                .setString("sPass", passwrd).list();

        Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
        boolean userExists = false;
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Users obj = (Users) iterator.next();
            System.out.print(obj.getUsers_email() + "\t"
                    + obj.getUsers_password() + "\n");
            System.out.println(obj.getMyRoles());
            System.out.println("Is Admin??? :" +obj.getMyRoles().toString().contains("Admin")); //gives if user is admin or not
            System.out.println(obj.getUser_id());
            userExists = true;
        }
        System.out.println(userExists);
        return userExists;
    }
}
```

Tabs.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs" style="background-color: #C8C8C8; font-family: fantasy;">
            <a href="employee">&nbsp; Employee Details </a>
            <a href="department"> Departments </a>
            <a href="designation"> Designation </a>
            <a href="logout"> Logout </a>
            <a href="user"> Users </a>
            <a href="roles"> Roles </a>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

users and Roles links must be displayed only if user is admin and this tabs.jsp is included in every page of the application.

Comment: I am curious.. why dont u wanna use Spring Security?

Comment: Initially i started building the application without using spring security so continuing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `User` object in `HttpSession` in Controller and check whether the logged in `User` is admin or not in jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs" style="background-color: #C8C8C8; font-family: fantasy;">
            <a href="employee">&nbsp; Employee Details </a>
            <a href="department"> Departments </a>
            <a href="designation"> Designation </a>
            <a href="logout"> Logout </a>
            <c:if test=${sessionScope.user.isAdmin}>
            <a href="user"> Users </a>
            <a href="roles"> Roles </a>
            </c:if>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```